# Mechanism to start action at installation before open

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to start an action (like sending a notification to a website) at the moment the app is installed, but before the users opens it.

So in case the user just downloads it and does not open it (ever) the notification will also be send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. As far as your application is concerned, you can't do anything until you can execute code, which you can't do until the application is launched by the user.